# What causes a bad quality image in VLC?

Tags: linux-mint, video, vlc

The video in VLC has like blurry horizontal lines that are mostly visible with writings. This doesn't affect the subtitles, only the video.
I tested the same video with VLC (left) and the default player on my system (Celluloid, right) and here are the results.
[image: VLC.png]
As you can see, the difference is really visible.
A few time back the quality was perfectly fine but I don't recall what has changed on the system since.
This happens on all types of video I tested (mp4 files and commercial dvd). I also tested these on VLC (3.0.8) on an other computer with no problems.
I'm on Linux Mint 20, the version of VLC was 3.0.9.2 when installed on the system from apt, then I compiled and installed version 3.0.11 but got the same results.
I tried tweaking video the settings of vlc (quite randomly) without success.
So does someone has an idea of what part of the system (drivers, libraries, compiler options) might cause that ?
Edit : [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58581/vlc-hd-bad-playback?rq=1) may be related. Tried turning off compiz with no results.

Comment: Have you tried removing (moving) vlc config files.

Comment: Looks like deinterlacing gone wrong (swapped field order?). Does this only happen with one video? Is it (supposed to be) interlaced? Have you tried playing with the deinterlacing options? Note that if you're using HW accelerated decoding, VLC typically defaults to also do the deinterlacing in hardware, which (at least for VDPAU) limits the available options compared to deinterlacing in software. Perhaps try disabling HW acceleration and see.

Comment: This happens in every video. I tried removing .config/vlc and I tried every deinterlace mode with no sucess. But I don't no what exactly these option are so maybe I didn't try the good option combo. Where is HW acceleration handled ? Is it in VLC options, linux settings or something related to my GPU ? btw I have Ryzen 5 CPU and RX 570 GPU with default system drivers.

Comment: Check if the de-interlacing method has some effect (Video menu)

Comment: When I do that, the image is a few pixels taller but has still blurry lines.

Answer (score 5):

I have the exact same issue, where the output seems badly interlaced in VLC only. I run VLC 3.0.12 Vetinari on Kubuntu 21.04 on a AMD Ryzen 5 1600 and a Radeon RX 570.

I solved this by changing the video output method to XVideo.

Tools > Preferences > Video > Output > XVideo output (XCB)

Comment: This problem happened to me on Debian 12 bookworm, VLC version 3.0.20, AMD Ryzen 5 5600X CPU and AMD Radeon RX 6800. I could fix it by changing the VLC output method as documented to "XVideo output (XCB)" or "X11 video output (XCB)". Thank you very much for providing this solution! (BTW: Dragonplayer does not have this problem. )

Answer (score 0):

You may [**Reset preferences from VLC**](https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:ResetPrefs/#Reset_preferences_from_VLC)

**macOS**
**Using VLC**
In case VLC still launches, open it. Select "VLC" menu -> "Preferences" and hit "Reset All" in the bottom left corner. VLC will ask for confirmation, reset and restart itself.

**macOS** **Manual deletion**

1. Quit the VLC application.
2. Use a Terminal and enter the following command: defaults delete org.videolan.vlc
3. Remove everything from `~/Library/Preferences` called "org.videolan.vlc.*". Use "Go To Folder" within the Finder's "Go" menu to show this folder.

**GNU/Linux**
Delete the `~/.config/vlc` and `~/.cache/vlc` folders or execute `vlc --reset-config` in a terminal.

Old versions of VLC had the data stored in ~/.vlc

**BeOS**
Delete the config/settings/vlcrc folders.

**iOS**
Delete the app from SpringBoard and re-download it from the App Store to fully reset the media library and settings.

**Android**
From the settings
In Settings, go to Applications → VLC → Clear data.

**Within the application**
Go to Preferences → Other to clean the history and the media database.